# Is Module Manager plugins Supported the zen cart version 1.5.0?

Tags: php, zen-cart, zen

I am try to install the `Module manager` for the `SSU(Simple SEO URL)` from last to day but i am not get the option of Module manager in admin pannel `Admin->Tools->Module Manager` after the upload all the file of the Module manager in my website.

I doing googling from there i got that `"Module manager does not support version 1.5"` so any other option for installation of SSU??

If Module manager support version 1.5.0 of zen cart then please help me to install it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module Manager was written for 1.3.x series and is not supported in 1.5.0. The author of the module abandoned Zen Cart and is now working on another platform.
SSU was a nice plugin, but also full of bugs...

Consider installing [Ceon's URI Mapping](http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=889) - it's IMHO the best. An alternative would be [Ultimate SEO URLs](http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=132), but it's not even close to Ceon's module.

You might also want to read an [interesting thread](http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?197166-SEO-URL-plugins-which-is-the-most-reliable) on that subject where you'll see that SEO URLs are probably better to be avoided because Zen Cart's dynamic URLs are well indexed by search engines.

Comment: thanks for your support but i have one confusion is that in the installation step number 4)"[Zen Cart Versions 1.3.0 - 1.3.8 Only] Enable Canonical URI Support." the Ceon's URI support the zen cart version 1.5.0??

Comment: thank my question is solved. The Ceon's URI Mapping is work on the zen cart version 1.5.0 thanks a lot @user1078494

Comment: user1078494 @ i have confusion that for the configuration of "RewriteCond" which .htaccess file i hava to modify??